# Binding WPF ContextMenu MenuItem to UserControl Property vs ViewModel Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, command, contextmenu

I'm struggling to understand what is going on with the ContextMenu. I know it is rendered as a separate window, with a separate visual tree, so we can't use relative binding to bind a command exposed as a property of the user control. e.g. the following **does not** work:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=TestCommand}" Header="Test" />
```

But, if you set the data context of the user control to a view model that exposes a command as a property, the following will work:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Header="Test" />
```

What I don't understand is, how is the ContextMenu inheriting the value of the DataContext if it is not part of the visual tree. I would expect both of these examples to behave the same (i.e. both work or both fail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second binding works because of so called "inheritance context". You can read about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2006/08/18/705116.aspx. Basically this is a kind of special case where some properties inherit data context of the owner object. Thus, for example, the inheritance context always works on properties of type `Freezable` (another interesting article about Freezables: http://drwpf.com/blog/category/freezables/).

Actually the article says that the inheritance context doesn't work on ContextMenu, but in version 4 they added it, so it actually works now as you've shown it in your example.