# WPF binding command to ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a problem with command binding in WPF. I have the following xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entity}" Name="Lst">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>                    
                <Button  Content="qwerty" Command="{Binding ElementName=Lst, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}" >
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>                                
                            <MenuItem Header="Send2" Command="{Binding ElementName=Lst, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>    
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As you can see Button and its ContextMenu have the similar command-bindings. But when i click button its command is firing and when i click context menu's item its command isn't firing. Where am i wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVVM binding command to contextmenu item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994241/mvvm-binding-command-to-contextmenu-item)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem before and solved it by passing the datacontext through the tag property of the container as below. I have it working on a grid ContextMenu but dont see any reason why this wont work on a button. Let me know if you have any problem

```
<Button  Content="qwerty" Tag="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=Lst}" Command="{Binding ElementName=Lst, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}"  >
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">                                
                            <MenuItem Header="Send2" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>    
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ContextMenu` being separate from the visual tree, you cannot bind with and element outside of it.

If you check your output window, you should have a message saying that it can't find the object "Lst"

A common and easy workaround would be to manually set the DataContext in code-behind (note: this is not breaking MVVM at all. You are just performing a pure UI operation of linking DataContexts together):

In your Xaml:

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu Opened="OnContextMenuOpened">                                
                            <MenuItem Header="Send2" Command="{Binding ElementName=Lst, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>
```

In code-behind:

```
public void OnContextMenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    (sender as ContextMenu).DataContext = Lst.DataContext;
}
```

You are therefore linking the `DataContext` every time the `ContextMenu` is opened (so if Lst's `DataContext` changes, your ContextMenu will as well)

Alternatively (cleaner if you are bound to use it a lot of times), get the `BindingProxy` from this article: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/  and it'll do the trick!

Comment: Yes, check the article I posted at the end of my answer. The `BindingProxy` perfectly does it